# Fullscreen Activity Template and Camera Preview

Tags: android

I created an activity using the fullscreen activity wizard and wanted to set a camera preview as the background as follows:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
 * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
 */
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

/**
 * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
 */
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

/**
 * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
private Camera camera;
private static final String TAG = "@id/app_name";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
            HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView
                                .animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(
            mDelayHideTouchListener);

    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content2);
    SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}

/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(camera != null){
        camera.stopPreview();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    camera = Camera.open(); 
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);


    parameters.setFlashMode("torch");

    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback); 


}

Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback()  
{ 
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)  
    { 


    }
};
```

I set a SurfaceView(fullscreen_content2) behind a transparent View(fullscreen_content), here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->

<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

<View
android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The camera preview works well, but the system doesn't hide the elements anymore. The elements get hidden only if I don't set the camera up! how can I get them to work together?